# The path of the executable that runs the script may differ across users

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash

I guess once upon a time, I was able to find this information by Googling but not this time.

I believe each script file (e.g. my.py, run.sh, etc) could have the path to an executable that is supposed to parse & run the script file. For example, a bash script file `run.sh` could start with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Then, my user will run it like:

```
$ ./run.sh
```

What if some users may not have `bash` there but has one under `/usr/sbin/`? Actually, my issue is Python3. Some users may have `python3` not as `/usr/bin/python3`. Some distros seem to install it as `/usr/bin/python37` while some other `/usr/bin/python`. Yet again, some do `$HOME/bin/virtualenv/python3`.

At least, what could I do to tell any (future) user's shell that my script should be run by `which python`. Or, even better if I could tell "Try `which python3`, and if not available, try `which python`."

Comment: Thats why so many good programmers try to develop and improve concepts like executables,docker,VM's etc. because there are many problems like the one you describe

Comment: For the Python example in particular, if you distribute your code as an installable package (e.g. something that can be installed with `pip install`) you don't need to worry about any of that.

Comment: @Stephen : If I user has an installation, which **only** has _python37_, but no _python_ (very unusual), tell him to create a  _python3_ symlink somewhere in his PATH pointing to his special _python37_, and stick in your script with `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the computer world, this first line that starts with `#!` is called `Shebang`.

There's no global agreement. Each family of `OS` applies in their own way.
The unique trusted solution is defining what `OS` you want to apply, configure according them and testing it.

Here, a good article if you want to go deeper with this concept: [Shebang (Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Answer (score 0):

A fairly common convention is to have at least `env` in /usr/bin. If we reasonably assume that the user has bash etc. in his PATH, you can start your script with

```
#!/urs/bin/env bash
```

Answer (score 0):

The problems with hard coded paths have been around since paths were invented and there are many conventions for dealing with them. Unix-like systems usually symlink `/bin/sh` to whatever shell is used on the system and you can trust that for the shebang in most situations - use `#!/bin/sh` for a bash-like shell unless you really do need the semantics of a specific shell.

The executor looks on $PATH for binaries to run. This same thing can be done with the shebang as `#!/usr/bin/env someprogram`. `env` will find the binary on the PATH and that's what will run. This is a good solution for python. `#!/usr/bin/env python3` will run the "python3" on the PATH. Most unix-like installs symlink a `python3` to the real one you should use. For instance on my machine at the moment

```
td:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
td:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Feb 10 17:59 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
```

Virtual environments modify PATH to add the `python3` you want for virtualization.